# first step on symfony 6

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I'm learning symfony 6 I wanted to create my first project but it didn't work. I have installed php8, symfony, composer, scoot, in their latest version. when I created the project with this command "symfony new my_project_directory --version="6.3.*" --webapp" I got this error "unable to run C:\Users\riro6\scoop\apps\composer \current\composer.phar create-project symfony/skeleton C:\Users\riro
6\Documents\PHP language\Symfony\tutorial-u 6.3.* --no-interaction"
I can't understand the problem. in advance thank you.

I checked all the versions of php, symfony, composer, scoot, everything is good.

Comment: Did you run `symfony check:requirements`?

Comment: You are missing the "`*`" from `symfony new my_project_directory --version="6.3.*" --webapp`

Answer (score 0):

To initialize a new project you may run the command below in the folder you want to create your new project:

```
symfony new [projectName] [options]
```

Replace `[projectName]` by the name of your project (and not the project directory) and replace `[options]` by --webapp as you consider using this option.

Other options may be interesting such as --docker (Symfony will auto add Docker services based on required packages) and --cloud (Auto generates a sensible Platform.sh configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Use composer to install Symfony 6.

composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"6.3.*" my_project_directory